# Initialise a select in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a `select` that should track a `myCoef` as a **float** value(not an object, but a float value).

I have the following code (CodePen [HERE](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/YqOMjo)):

```js
function theController($scope) {
  
  $scope.coefs = [
    {name:'mm', val:1/1000},
    {name:'cm', val:1/100},
    {name:'m', val:1}
  ];  

  $scope.myCoef = 1/100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-app>
   
  <div ng-controller="theController">
   
    <select ng-model="myCoef" 
            ng-options="coef.name for coef in coefs track by coef.val">
    </select>{{myCoef}}
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I correctly initialise my `select`, in order to keep a float value in myCoef?

Comment: I'would like to have myCoef as **float** value, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use As syntax and remove track by.

PS : If someone knows why i have to remove track by he can edit my answer because i don't really know why.

```js
function theController($scope) {
  
  $scope.coefs = [
    {name:'mm', val:1/1000},
    {name:'cm', val:1/100},
    {name:'m', val:1}
  ];  

  $scope.myCoef = 1/100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-app>
   
  <div ng-controller="theController">
   
    <select ng-model="myCoef" 
            ng-options="coef.val as coef.name for coef in coefs">
    </select>{{myCoef}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Strange.. i add to remove the track by to have it working... Check my edited answer

Comment: super! I don't really understand this syntax, but seem to work! you can remove the incorect first edit now ;)

Answer (score 0):

A little strange syntax. Following the [Walfrat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36885383/961631), examples how to init by val, or by name the initial value (without passing via `$scope.myCoef = $scope.coefs[1]` syntax)

```js
function theController($scope) {
  
  $scope.coefs = [
    {name:'mm', val:1/1000},
    {name:'cm', val:1/100},
    {name: 'm', val:1}
  ];  
  $scope.myCoefVal = 1/1000;
  $scope.myCoefName = 'cm';
}
```

```html
<body ng-app>   
  <div ng-controller="theController">
   Init by value - myCoefVal=1/100 <br>
    <select ng-model="myCoefVal" 
            ng-options="coef.val as coef.name for coef in coefs">
    </select><br>
    now myCoefVal={{myCoefVal}}
    <br/><br/>
    Init by name - myCoefName='cm'<br>
    <select ng-model="myCoefName" 
            ng-options="coef.name as coef.name for coef in coefs">
    </select><br>
    now myCoefName='{{myCoefName}}'
  </div>
</body>
```